# how to send push notifications from php to IOS using FCM

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter

I am trying to push notifications from php to IOS using FCM.
here is my code.

```
   $serverKey = 'MYKEY';

    define('API_ACCESS_KEY', $serverKey);
    $registrationIds = ($vals['registration_ids']);
    $msg=$vals['data'];

    // prep the bundle

    $fields = array
    (
        'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
        'data'              => $msg
    );

    $headers = array
    (
        'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    echo $result;
```

But it always says:

> {"multicast_id":9213457463518601541,"success":0,"failure":7,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"InvalidRegistration"},{"error":"InvalidRegistration"},{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}

Comment: it  means your code is running fine, however the mobiles which are supposed to receive the message do not have the correct SENDER ID in their app. Please have them correct it.

Comment: They have SENDER ID. But how i check that SENDER ID is correct or not? Thanks for reply.

Comment: You can not check , ask them to check in logcat if the SENDER ID is matching with what you or your team have provided from FCM Console

Answer (score 0):

Try that code :

```
<?php



     public function notification($registrationIds,$body,$title)
     {

    $body;
    $title;
    $registrationIds; 


        //#API access key from Google API's Console
         if(!defined('AIdfSyCd8ha2wop84LKtpQvRmLpeTg2CEiY8Z')){
            define( 'AIdfSyCd8ha2wop84LKtpQvRmLpeTg2CEiY8Z', 'AAAA61DTuxA:APA93BGY4CXhKXJ2tPjoh3dnhbkmn1bGmfFj6Q7JJaBrdqKI106NFc3LZQTHy5i8WO5JoQBalrCIW_Cs2pGUz5mp1OL9SVcx0oH-hRGGpaeqV6hF-UDqJAlWAjGwyQM-oSl98ye_zMDi' );

          }
         $registrationIds = $registrationIds;
        //#prep the bundle
             $msg = array
                  (
                'body'  => $body,
                'title' => $title,
                'icon'  => 'myicon',/*Default Icon*/
                'sound' => 'mySound'/*Default sound*/
                  );
            $fields = array
                    (
                        'to'        => $registrationIds,
                        'notification'  => $msg
                    );


            $headers = array
                    (
                        'Authorization: key=AAAA61DTuxA:APA93BGY4CXhKXJ2tPjoh3dnhbkmn1bGmfFj6Q7JJaBrdqKI106NFc3LZQTHy5i8WO5JoQBalrCIW_Cs2pGUz5mp1OL9SVcx0oH-hRGGpaeqV6hF-UDqJAlWAjGwyQM-oSl98ye_zMDi',
                        'Content-Type: application/json'
                    );
        #Send Reponse To FireBase Server    
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
                $result = curl_exec($ch );
                curl_close( $ch );
        #Echo Result Of FireBase Server
         $result;
     }

?>
```